# Tool to convert arbitrary MIME emails to plain text? (best effort)

Tags: text-processing, email, text

I'm wondering if there is a command-line tool to do this:

> Take as input an arbitrary MIME email and output a best-effort guess at a plain-text version of the email message.

Here is my justification for why it's a tricky problem. If we knew that an email was encoded in HTML, then we could use e.g. lynx -dump or html2text. But we can't always tell for sure if that's the case, or even if we can, it might be a multipart/alternative message with a plain text section, in which case it's not clear to me when we should trust the sender's plain-text version versus convert the html part ourselves. And on top of all this, with arbitrary multi-part emails it's not always easy to identify the message part to begin with.

Because of all this, I'm not asking for a tool that works perfectly on every email, just one that gives its best effort and would do better than if I try to write such a program myself.

It seems to me that such code must exist in many places where various email clients do this, but searching hasn't turned up any tools to just solve this problem...